# Dot sourcing a function call is not allowing me to call my function why could this be?

Tags: function, powershell

I am trying to write a module that calls on a script containing a series of functions I use in other modules. I have done this in the past with success but I seem to be stuck in a strange scenario, here is my situation:
When I copy the function code directly into my script and call it locally it works fine. 
But when I

```
. <exact path to my function>
```

call to load my function it loads fine BUT when I then try to call a function in the file it throws an error stating the function does not exist but as I stated earlier when I copy the function into my script it executes just fine

My function is called NetworkScan

I have tried to convert the function to a module and use import-module this ends up with the exact same result
I have also tried to place the function script in the same location as my module and then set the location of my script to $PSScriptRoot and then using a . ./function.ps1 call also same issue (this where I am currently at)

```
Set-Location $PSScriptRoot

$ScannedIPs=@()  
$RPIip= @()  

$SIP = "192.168.220.1"  
$EIP = "192.168.220.254"  

#load function script   
. .\function.ps1  

$ScannedIPs = NetworkScan -SIP $SIP -EIP $EIP  
....
```

this is a how my function NetworkScan is defined in function.ps1:

```
 function NetworkScan{  
 Param(  
 [Parameter(Position = 0, Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true,   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]  
 [Alias("SIP")]  
 $StartScanIP,  
 [Alias("EIP")]  
 $EndScanIP)  
....  
}
```

expected results:
my function is called to pick up IP's on the network and their MAC addresses this is then returned to the module script to continue to process

Actual results:

```
NetworkScan : The term 'NetworkScan' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At C:\Users\User\Downloads\Script_in_Dev\xxx_PowerCycler_10min.ps1:109 char:15
+ $ScannedIPs = NetworkScan -SIP $SIP -EIP $EIP
+               ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (NetworkScan:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

EDIT:
I commented out all the other functions in my function.ps1 file and except for NetworkScan now I seem to be able to use NetworkScan via the above method however I would like to fix my function.ps1 file so I can use all the items in this file. Does anyone know why this would happen, being that I can load the file but not use any of this functions? As I am not getting syntax error its hard for me to understand where I went wrong if I could be pointed in the right direction I should be able to figure this out.

Comment: your function loads for me, auto-completion works, and the dummy code i added runs. i had to run it ... but once run it was all there. ///// are you SURE the file is where you think it is? you are using a relative path in your demo code ... try using the explicit, specific path.

Comment: I think I'm closer to solving my issue I commented all my other functions in my functions.ps1 script except for NetwrokScan and now it worked therefore I must have a previous function or snippet of code either changing my scope or another issue I have to figure out any hints you have as to wht could cause the rest of my functions not to load properly? your help is appreciated Thank you for confirming my syntax for dot sourcing is correct and that I am not going crazy.

Comment: you are very welcome ... glad to be a bit of a help now and then! [*grin*]